# Classic ASP HTTP Redirect for www.test.shropshire.sch.uk to www.test.co.uk

Tags: http, redirect, asp-classic

I have two website domains one is similar to www.test.shropshire.sch.uk and the other is www.test.co.uk.

Both websites point to the same Windows Classic ASP web hosting account on our windows server.

So both domains are serving the exact same website (2 domains pointing to same web server).

As Google will see this as two websites (duplicate content) we would prefer the www.test.shropshire.sch.uk domain to point to the www.test.co.uk one.

The Default.asp page already redirects to homep.asp?PageRef=1 for the homepage.

I don't have access to the www.test.shropshire.sch.uk domain and the domain controller has said they can't setup domain forwarding for some reason and advised me to do a HTTP redirect.

So the problem that needs to be solved is I need to setup redirects from all webpages and subfolders of www.test.shropshire.sch.uk and redirect them to the same place but as www.test.co.uk so that in the address bar we never see the domain www.test.shropshire.sch.uk but always see www.test.co.uk.

But also if someone navigates to the "true" website (www.test.co.uk) it still needs to work as normal so that the HTTP redirects don't interfere or break the pages.

So these redirects need to work on both domains essentially always showing www.test.co.uk in the URL Address bar.

Thanks for reading, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S. I usually work on Linux and am pretty good with .htaccess rewriting URLs just not so good with Windows equivalents**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you don't have access to the "domain", but do you have access to IIS?

Comment: We may be able to get access to the IIS, can you do redirects in there?

Comment: It'd be easier in IIS as you can also serve proper 301 headers.

Open IIS, create a new site of the domain you want to move away from (therefore set correct host headers). The on the home directory tab, specify redirection to a URL.

In the redirect box, type in the new domain name and add $S$Q to the end. Eg: http://www.correct-domain-name.com$S$Q

Then tick the box to redirect to the exact URL and make it a permanent redirect for the resource.

This will also then preserve querystrings, SEO, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting this bashed together bit of classic-asp in an include and put the include at the top of the relevant pages.

```
<%
if Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")="www.test.shropshire.sch.uk" then
dim StrRedir
StrRedir="http://www.test.co.uk"
StrRedir=StrRedir&Request.ServerVariables("URL")
if trim(Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING"))<>"" then StrRedir=StrRedir&"?"&Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")
response.redirect(StrRedir)
end if
%>
```

Comment: Within Google.co.uk both the domains are competing for rankings as they are the same website, if we implement this fix to all of the pages on the website will Google crawl the pages and be redirected to www.test.co.uk and recognise this as the new true website? Will they be recgonised as permanent redirects for SEO purposes?

Comment: I am not an SEO person but I would assume that Google would ignore a redirect. Could you put a robots.txt in the root of just the site you don't want indexed. Failing that rewrite my example to output a clientside redirect and a noindex metatag. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93708?hl=en